# Scala: Type annotation of parameter resets ClassTag to Option and spoils type matching

Tags: scala, jvm, type-erasure, classtag

I have a trait with a type parameter. Inside this trait I want to define a method which checks if an object matches the type parameter. So far, this works, as I want it to work:

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
trait MyTrait[A <: AnyVal]{
    def hasType(x: AnyVal)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]) = x match {
        case _: A => true
        case _    => false
    }
}

object MyObject extends MyTrait[Int]

println(MyObject.hasType(5))   // returns true
println(MyObject.hasType(5.0)) // returns false
```

The problem occurs when `MyTrait`-objects are parameters of a class, like here:

```scala
class WrappingClass(myObjects: Seq[MyTrait[_]]) {
    def hasType(x: AnyVal) = {
        myObjects.foreach(
            mo => println(mo.hasType(x))
        )
    }
}

object AnotherObject extends MyTrait[Double]
val wrappingObject = new WrappingClass(Seq(MyObject, AnotherObject))
wrappingObject.hasType(5)   // prints only "true"
wrappingObject.hasType(5.0) // prints only "true"
```

So bassicly the type annotation `Seq[MyTrait[_]]` of the parameter turns my ClassTag to a general Object and ruins type matching. I really would like to avoid writing the `hasType` method in each object that inherits from the trait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a class with a `ClassTag` context bound (since those bounds are not utilizable in traits).
If you replace `MyTrait` as:

```
abstract class MyTrait[A <: AnyVal: ClassTag] {
    def hasType(x: AnyVal) = x match {
      case _: A => true
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

it will works as you expect

Comment: `abstract class MyTrait` seems to be closer to `trait MyTrait` and I will add abstract members in the following work so this seems to be better for me. Thank you a lot!

Comment: you are welcome, I've updated the answer with your advice